# IT Certifications

Tags: technology

I've been working in the IT Industry for 6 years now. I've largely been working in call centers. I've done Tier 1, Tier 2, and Tier 3 support. I've been a team lead and mentor to other employees.

Right now I work for a contractor that just lost its contract. I'll be eventually moved over to a new contractor. I won't lose my job... but I'm starting to think about my future a bit more. I make good money where I work, but I could always make more. Also, it sucks being shifted to new contractors all the time.

Instead of being on the phone, I would like to get hands on with PCs. I think it would be interesting becoming a IT repair technician, or someone who actually works on computers in the flesh.

What certifications would you recommend I aim for? I have none, just the experience under my belt that I got at the call centers and what I've done at home, taking PCs apart and putting them back together.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Are certifications worth it?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/44/64132)

Comment: Nothing beats experience but certain areas of IT absolutely require certification (Networking comes to mind) while others do not (Software development can get away without). My advice would be to figure out what job you want, what certs are available and then ask around to hiring managers to see if pursuing that cert is worth it.

Answer (score 4):

There is no good answe ro *which certifications are useful ?* question. Everybody knows they are all, ummm... crap... pardon the language. If you have a good memory, you can pass any of those tests without knowing a lick about computers at the end.

Let me tell you something else. Even though it looks glamorous from the far, getting into the guts of the PC to fix it, is a dying practice. With PC class computes selling less than $200 nowadays, almost nobody fixes computer parts anymore. Chucking whole god damn thing and getting a new one is easier and more cost efficient in the sense of total cost of ownership.

What you might want to pursue instead is becoming a systems administrator or engineer. If you have 4-5 years call center experience, you can show it as relevant knowledge and apply for positions looking for sysadmins. After all what sysadmins do is to deal with the problems that call centers or in other words, front lines can't solve or don't have time to solve. And for being a sysadmin, there is no single certification path. It all depends what kind of systems you will administer. Best is to get in the door as a junior sysadmin (may be get a little pay cut) and go for your certification, while you are on the job. There are many places providing after hours classes and online classes for people who work a full time job.

Comment: "Even though it looks glamorous from far, getting into the guts of a PC to fix it, is a dying practice" - **UPDATE**: it's dead

Comment: "If you have a good memory, you can pass any of those tests without knowing a lick about computers at the end" - Absolutely true when it comes to Citrix certifications for instance, Knowledge regurgitation over practice.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the company you're working for. I wouldn't be surprised that people wouldn't know what the certificate was for. I have a Zend Certification for PHP and many people ask me what that is even though I'm applying for a PHP position.

Point is it entirely depends on the company.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking as a former sysadmin, IT repair technicians are a dime a dozen and the competition is fierce - they're like the 1st line of hands-on IT support, the bottom of the food chain. I'd be surprised if your experience wasn't enough already for a switch as you're already ahead of 99% of the population.

If you're set on moving, you could kick off with CompTIA A+, N+ and S+ which will give you a bit of paper showing employers you know what you're talking about (plus, they're cheap and easy) but in my experience the best employers are willing to train you up - my last employer put me through numerous Citrix, Microsoft and VMWare certs and it was entirely worth it for the role. Hands on experience is great, having experience and the certs is even better.

Answer (score 0):

My philosophy has always been that any position that requires a certification isn't worth pursuing.

Your best bet is to simply start doing it on your own.  Pick up a few broken PCs and take them apart, pick up a cheap book on PC repair, and get to it.  then when you know your way inside the guts, do some volunteer PC repair for local charities and then put that on your resume to transition over to what you want to do.

Real experience is always better than a cert.  And if an employer doesn't think so, then that employer values paper over experience and is NOT someone you want to work for anyway.